# Save a new attribute taxonomy in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

i've register new column in woocommerce_attribute taxonomies, and i want to save my custom field to my new column, i'm using woocommerce_after_edit_attribute_fields hook to display an input and woocommerce_attribute_updated/added to catch the data of a new attribute, but when i try update the tableit dosent really do nothing, maybe there is some solution with woocommerce action/filter that i dont know about ... thank for any help :)

```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_added', 'my_save_wc_attribute_my_field',10,2 );
   add_action( 'woocommerce_attribute_updated', 'my_save_wc_attribute_my_field',10,2 );
   function my_save_wc_attribute_my_field($id,$data ) {
if ( is_admin() && isset( $_POST['my_field'] ) ) {
    global $wpdb;


    $attribute_name= 'wwowowowwo';
    $attribute_slug = $data['attribute_slug'];
    $attribute_label = $data['attribute_label'];
    $attribute_orderby = $data['attribute_orderby'];
    $attribute_public = $data['attribute_public'];
    $attribute_maple = $_POST['my_field'];

           
    $arrd = array(
        'attribute_name' => $attribute_name,
        'attribute_label' => $attribute_label,
        'attribute_orderby' => $attribute_orderby,
        'attribute_public' => $attribute_public,
        'maple_attribute_types' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['my_field']),

     );
     $arrid = array(
        'ID' => $id,
     );
      

     // save new field into attribute taxonomies
     $wpdb->update("wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies", $arrd,$arrid);


        echo  $attribute_orderby;
        echo $id;
        echo $attribute_maple;
}
```

}

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246687/97483

Comment: thank you :) it helped me to figure it out, can you guide me to how can i display the new taxonomy on the add new attribute table before "terms"

Answer (score 0):

I've used the function from [Creating custom attribute...](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/244335/creating-custom-woocommerce-attribute-taxonomies-from-a-plugin/246687#246687)

and inside `process_Add_attribute` I've removed

```
 // flush_rewrite_rules();
 // delete_transient( 'wc_attribute_taxonomies' );
```